# How to obtain the languageid in a Liferay theme with velocity

Tags: internationalization, liferay, velocity

For the current theme im creating there are multiple images that require to change based on the current language.

For example if the user is visiting the page in english we would load image_**languageid**.jpg

How can you replace *languageid* with the actual id of the language in velocity & liferay?

Is this a good technique or is there a nicer one?

Comment: Does this have to be in a theme velocity files or article templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this line in `init_custom.vm` or `portal_normal.vm`

```
#set ($language_id = $themeDisplay.getLanguageId())
```