# Change Locale in Velocity in Liferay theme

Tags: liferay, portlet, velocity, liferay-theme

I am using velocity in liferay theme.

In init_custom.vm file I want to include CSS for both English and Arabic.

Which CSS works where it depends on present locale selected?

Like:

```
If(locale=="eng"){
 my eng css
}
else{
 my arbic css
}
```

How do I write this in velocity?

Please give some idea or details.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was already given in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254603/how-to-obtain-the-languageid-in-a-liferay-theme-with-velocity). This is what you'll need to do:

Put this line in your init.vm

```
#set ($language_id = $themeDisplay.getLanguageId())
```

Then you can add condition like following:

```
#If($language_id == "en_US")
    my eng css
#else
    my arbic css
#end
```

And add $language_id as a class in your html or body tag in portal_normal.vm. You'll get a language ID like "en_US", [here's a list](http://www.liferay.com/en/web/manish.gupta/blog/-/blogs/liferay-now-have-34-languages-ootb).